# Inferring generic function type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

I am creating a function to create Redux actions (like `createAction` from redux toolkit). I need a function that will return action generator and I would like this generator to be generic based on what types are provided to creator function.

```js
const createGenericAction = <T extends string>(type: T) => <
  A extends {},
  B extends {}
>(
  payloadGenerator: (a: A) => B
) => {
  const factory = (payload: A) => ({
    type,
    payload: payloadGenerator(payload),
  });
  factory.toString = (() => type) as () => T;

  return factory;
};
```

This is how the creator function looks like now (the `toString` implementation is due to compatibility with redux-toolkit).

It is working okay when `payloadGenerator` is not generic, so:

```js
const someAction = createGenericAction('someAction')(
  (payload: { a: number; b: string }) => payload
);
```

has correct type.

Although, when `payloadGenerator` is generic, whole type inferring falls apart:

```js
const someAction = createGenericAction('someAction')(
  <T extends string>(payload: { value: T }) => payload
);
```

```
Argument of type '<T extends string>(payload: { value: T; }) => { value: T; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: {}) => { value: string; }'.
  Types of parameters 'payload' and 'a' are incompatible.
    Property 'value' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ value: string; }'.ts(2345)
```

**More complicated example**

```js
enum Element {
  Elem1 = 'elem1',
  Elem2 = 'elem2',
}

type ElementValueMapper = {
  [Element.Elem1]: string;
  [Element.Elem2]: number;
};

const someAction = createGenericAction('someAction')(
  <T extends Element>(payload: { e: T; value: ElementValueMapper[T] }) =>
    payload
);
```

Such action should allow calls:

```js
someAction({ e: Element.Elem1, value: 'string' }); // okay
```

```js
someAction({ e: Element.Elem2, value: 5 }); // okay
```

But disallow:

```js
someAction({ e: Element.Elem1, value: 5 }); // error value should be type string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've tracked that issue comes from reimplementing `toString` of Function. The idea is that after assigning function to `toString`, `factory` is no longer treated as "TypeScript function", but as following interface:

```
{
  (payload: A): {
    payload: B;
  };
  toString(): A;
}
```

And part of this interface is correct, but whole type of `factory` is not what I desire. Actually, every function in JS (so in TS also) is of `function` type and comes from `Function` prototype, which do contain `toString`, but TypeScript does distinguish these types and `Function` is not really often used.

Without too much off-topic, solution is to assert type to `factory`:

```js
const createGenericAction = <A extends string>(code: A) => <
  A extends {},
  B extends {}
>(
  payloadGenerator: (a: A) => B
) => {
  const factory: (payload: A) => { payload: B } = (payload: A) => ({
    payload: payloadGenerator(payload),
  });
  factory.toString = () => code;

  return factory;
};
```

Comment: I'm curious how redux-toolkit works around this issue, if even

Comment: @TomaszBłachut
It doesn't, https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/584